# Azure Search Indexer - excluding document types not working in the portal

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I just setup an indexer using the portal to index documents in a blob storage. When I try to change the advanced settings to exclude image files (png, jpeg etc.), the settings are not saved.

I can also not find anywhere, using the GUI, to set excludedFileNameExtensions...

Any help would be appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this; it is a bug in Azure Search portal. The fix will be deployed in the next few days. In the meantime, you can work around by updating the indexer programmatically, using either REST API or .NET SDK.